# r: generating fitted vs. actual plots using lm and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I'm running a linear model and want to create the framework to visualize my `actual` vs. `fitted` values using `ggplot2` in a fast, reproducible way so that when I run a model, I can quickly pull-up the latest run and see where I have the greatest residuals.

I've created a sample data set to run this on, but end-up running into errors when added the fitted values to the visualization (`actual` values alone are straightforward). See example code below:

```
# creating sample data set
dfmodel<- data_frame(seq(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-01-10'), by= 'day'), rnorm(10, 12, 3), rnorm(10, 14, 5))
colnames(dfmodel)<- c( 'date','var1', 'var2')

# running model
lmodel<- lm(var1~ var2, data= dfmodel)

# applying fitted values to my data frame
dfmodel$fitted<- lmodel$fitted.values

# creating ggplot object for visualization
lmodel_plot<- ggplot(dfmodel, aes(x= date, y= var1))
lmodel_plot + geom_line(y= fitted) 

# attempting to layer in fitted value, but generating this error:
Error in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

The goal is to have my `actual` and `fitted` values in one chart, on the same axis (and to eventually layer in the residuals for a more complete picture).

Comment: Change the last line to ```lmodel_plot + geom_line(aes(y = fitted))```, you just forgot the ```aes```/aesthetic part.

Comment: `ggplot` also has the function `geom_smooth(method = "lm")` that will show the fitted line. That saves the step of creating the additional column in your `data.frame` if you only want to view the relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plot function was off, your model, Var1 vs Var2 so you would want to plot y=Vars and x=Var1.

```
library(ggplot2)
# creating ggplot object for visualization
lmodel_plot<- ggplot(dfmodel, aes(x= var2, y= var1)) +
  geom_point() +geom_line(aes(y= fitted)) 

print(lmodel_plot)
```

You needed to include the aesthetic part for the fitted values in the `geom_line` and you needed to add `geom_point` to plot the actual points.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the aes() for geom_line

```
# creating sample data set
dfmodel<- data_frame(seq(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-01-10'), by= 'day'), 
rnorm(10, 12, 3), rnorm(10, 14, 5))
colnames(dfmodel)<- c( 'date','var1', 'var2')

# running model
lmodel<- lm(var1~ var2, data= dfmodel)

# applying fitted values to my data frame
dfmodel$fitted<- lmodel$fitted.values

# creating ggplot object for visualization
lmodel_plot <- ggplot(dfmodel, aes(x= date, y= var1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= fitted))
```

Comment: To add why the original attempt gave such a confusing error-message: `fitted` is also a function, which means `geom_line` tried to use it as a kind of parameter, which had to be repeated for the full length (just like `geom_line(color='red)` will repeat "red" for all points)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both points and lines. Otherwise there's no way(for this data) to have both values plotted as `geom_line` unless someone knows of a way.

```
dfmodel %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date,var1))+geom_point(colour="red")+geom_line(aes(y=fitted))
```